# how to correctly merge here

Tags: typescript, generics, merge

consider this setup:

```
interface A { x: string }
interface B { y: string }

type AB = A & B


class Merger<T extends AB> {
  merge(a: A): void {
    const 
      b: B = { y: 'hello' },
      ab: T = { ...a, ...b } //compile error see below
    ; 
  }
}
```

Here the Error:

```
Type '{ y: string; x: string; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'{ y: string; x: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', 
    but 'T' could be instantiated with a diff
```

If I am getting this right, than this means that `AB` could have more Properties? What I basically want to do is to add some fixed properties to `A`, like a timestamp. How could I come around this error

Comment: By using generic type `T`, you mean that it would work with anything which is a sub-type of AB, e.g: T is `{x: string; y: string; z:string}`. However: `{...a, ...b}` is `AB`, not T because there is no `z` property in `ab`.

Comment: Or worse, `new Merger<{x: "x", y: "y", z: string}>()`

Comment: @philipp, I don't understand why your code is generic at all.  Can you explain why [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IB4C5kDOYUoA5sgL4CwAUKJLIigEKbICe+RJI51NtBABs4BAsgCy0UtEy1kyALbSIACjj5UASnwA3APbAAJnJoKFCfSCLzzCgEb5WAXjadkAcgAWEIUP0elAA0tnZwjmjIAGTILmwAdIlwQciJ8faUANy2-BRAA) does not suffice?  If your use case needs generics, please elaborate

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the error message, you need instantiated T,so:

```
interface A { x: string }
interface B { y: string }
type AB = A & B

interface T extends AB {
}

class Merger {
    merge(a: A): void {
        const b: B = { y: 'hello' }
        const ab: T = { x: "a", y: 'b' };
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question; the error message doesn't say that you *need* to instantiate `T`; it says that the generic type parameter `T` could be instantiated with subtypes of `AB` to which `AB` is not assignable.  Such as in `new Merger<{x: "x", y: "y", z: number>()`.